# Updating a dataframe with some missing values using a subset dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, missing-data

I am trying to update the missing values of a dataframe in pandas with a smaller subset but cannot seem to get pd.merge, df.loc or pd.join to work.

The scenario is like this: I have a Dataframe `df` such that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"EmpId":[1,2,3,...,99,100],
                   "Name":['Fred','Barney','Wilma',...,'Bam-Bam','Pebbles'], 
                   "Age":[40,35,NaN,...,5,NaN]}
```

And I get a new dataframe `df1` like:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"EmpId":[3,...,100],
                    "Age":[30,...,6]})
```

The "EmpId"'s in `df1` are a non-sequential set of id's which exist in `df` with "Age" values which are `NaN` in `df`. I am trying to fill the missing entries in `df` without duplicating or otherwise affecting the existing values.
I have tried `pd.merge`, which tries to add `df1` as new columns in `df` (even when using `suffixes=(False,False)`, `pd.join` has a similar effect)
I have tried using `df.loc[df.EmpId == df1.EmpId, 'Age'] = df1.loc[df1.EmpId == df.EmpId, 'Age']` but whilst I can parse the information I require, won't seem to update `df`, it continues to have the `NaN` values.
I have tried `df.update(df1)` but get a Value Error.
I've even tried a `for...if...` construct with `df.loc` but none of these seem to work as I intend.
`df` and `df1` have different shapes.
If anyone has any ideas where I'm going wrong, I would appreciate your input.

Comment: Your minimal example should be compete, please do not use `...` and provide the exact matching expected output.

Comment: I think if you use `set_index` to make `"EmpId"` the index, then `df.update(df1)` should work, but I'm not sure why it's giving a `ValueError` now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you can use merge + additional operations on result columns, while making sure you don't change the original values with `ifnull` function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"EmpId":[1,2,3,99,100],
                   "Name":['Fred','Barney','Wilma','Bam-Bam','Pebbles'], 
                   "Age":[40,35,np.NaN,5,np.NaN]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"EmpId":[3,100],
                    "Age":[30,6]})

df = df.merge(df1, on="EmpId", how="left", suffixes=("", "_filled"))

def ifnull(val, replace):
    if val is None or pd.isna(val):
        return replace
    return val

df["Age"] = df[["Age", "Age_filled"]] \
    .apply(lambda row: ifnull(row["Age"], row["Age_filled"]), axis=1)

df.drop("Age_filled", axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   EmpId     Name   Age
0      1     Fred  40.0
1      2   Barney  35.0
2      3    Wilma  30.0
3     99  Bam-Bam   5.0
4    100  Pebbles   6.0
```

This will only work if `EmpId` are in fact unique, as in your example.